# "The Dataflow appears to be stuck" after upgrade from Dataflow 1.9.0 to 2.0.0

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I'm getting this message from a couple pipelines (though not all) a day after upgrading from Dataflow 1.9.0 to 2.0.0.

"Workflow failed. Causes: (b5893b31713a87d5): The Dataflow appears to be stuck. Please reach out to the Dataflow team at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-dataflow."

Job ID: 2017-08-26_12_52_36-13586241835034779577

Comment: another Job ID: 2017-08-26_14_09_50-15565496177338196866

Comment: It looks like this happened because the job took an extremely long time to load data from BigQuery (a BigQuery export job took ~3 hours). Did the previous runs of this job, that worked well, take similar time and export similar amounts of data?

Comment: Similar amounts of data - yes. The only change in the job was the Dataflow upgrade. Similar time - no. We noticed a performance degradation reading / writing to BQ after the upgrade, as did other devs at our company.

Comment: Thanks. Did this job previously take less than 3 hours? I'm trying to understand it it's specifically Dataflow or BigQuery that became slower for you.

Comment: It looks like previous / subsequent runs of this job took 3 - 5.5 hours total. (We had to downgrade to 1.9.0 after a lot of failures). Here are some Job IDs: 2017-08-27_19_57_31-5033290381853120428, 2017-08-23_10_32_23-16564102868707795439, 2017-08-22_07_57_43-6509104231026662538

Comment: I see, thanks. We've identified a bug on the service side that causes the stuckness detector to falsely fire in this case, and are working on a fix.

Comment: great. would you mind updating here when the fix is rolled out? we are blocked from upgrading until then.

Comment: I believe it's been rolled out already. Are you still experiencing the issue?

Comment: good to know! we haven't attempted the upgrade since the original post, but we'll give it a try and comment here if we see the issue again.